# Jquery handle the buttons in a table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I haven't found a good answer to this question that makes sense.

I have a table being displayed and at the end of each row in the table is a button to join the game in the row.

the button is just

```
<td><button class="btn-u btn-u-xs rounded-2x btn-u-default" id="<?php echo $game['id']; ?>"type="button">Join League</button></td>
```

Each buttons ID is the id of the row of game the user is joining. So when a user clicks the button of that row i need jquery to run a post to save the user in the game

I have the backend PHP code done to actually save the user but I do not know how to jquery to send the post with the button ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the buttons that is all the same to use as a selector in jQuery. I gave them all a class of join-league. Then listen for the click event on those buttons. You can grab the game id and use it to either submit a form or make an ajax call so the user is saved in that game.

HTML

```
<td><button class="btn-u btn-u-xs rounded-2x btn-u-default join-league" id="<?php echo $game['id']; ?>"type="button">Join League</button></td>
```

JS

```
$('.join-league').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var gameId = $(this).attr('id');
    ... do stuff, submit form or make ajax call
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ouomkk1k/ JSFiddle example

Comment: hmm i tried that it didn't work, i think its because the class is so big that just adding join-league at the end wont work

Comment: Works for me, I added a link to JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is give all of your buttons a class name like "save-user".  Then, attach a listener to them by class using jQuery and accessing their individual ID's with `$(this).attr('id')`.

Example:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="button" id="1">B1</button></td>
        <td><button class="button" id="2">B2</button></td>
        <td><button class="button" id="3">B3</button></td>
        <td><button class="button" id="4">B4</button></td>
        <td><button class="button" id="5">B5</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').on('click', function(){
       alert($(this).attr('id')); 
    });
});
```

JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vvtr7kv6/)